# Why my elements shows without style?

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, tags

I recently start to create an application with phonegap and jquery mobile that loads a json an create a elements this is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#boton").click(function(){
                    $.getJSON("json url",function(data){
                        var instrucciones = data.Instrucciones;
                        document.getElementById("titulos").innerHTML = instrucciones;
                        var acordeonJSON = $('<div data-role="collapsible" id="accordeon"><h3>hi</h3><p>Hello</p></div>');
                        $.each(data.Items,function(llave,valor){
                            if(valor.nombreItem !="")
                            {
                                $("#accordeon").append(acordeonJSON);
                            }
                        });
                    });//Llave getJSON
                });//Llave boton click
            });

        </script>
```

This is my Html structure

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header" id="titulo">
            <h1 id="titulos"></h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="div1">
            <button id="boton">Presioname</button>
            <div id="instrucciones"></div>

            <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" id="accordeon">
                <!--In this part i want to show the content of my json-->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

My question is why i cant create my elements in jquery, the created elements shows without style.

Answer (score 0):

After appending all the new dom elements within the `collapsibleset`, call `$("#accordeon").collapsibleset( "refresh" ).enhanceWithin();`

**For example:**

```
$("#boton").click(function(){
   var acordeonJSON = $('<div data-role="collapsible" id="accordeon1"><h3>hi</h3><p>Hello</p></div>'); 
   $("#accordeon").append(acordeonJSON).collapsibleset("refresh").enhanceWithin();
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lqu285dc/)**